# Delay Task processing of object if object with same ID is currently being processed by another Task

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Let's say I have objects:

```
ObjectA(
int ID,
List<ObjectB> items
)

ObjectB(
int ItemId,
string value
)
```

From RabbitMQ I fetch maximum of 10 messages, `prefetchCount = 10`, where after deserialization every message becomes object of type `ObjectA`.

*One `ObjectA` can have multiple `ObjectB` with same `ItemId`.*

All that is done in .NET Core 3.1 background worker:

```
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
            // code omitted for brevity
            // register event that handles message received
            consumer.Received += MessageReceived;
        }
    }
```

After deserialization for every `ObjectA`, I run two tasks, `taskA` and `taskB`, which is not currently important.

Important is `TaskA` that processes all items of `ObjectA` - List of `ObjectB`. `taskA` also runs multiple tasks for every `ObjectB`.

**How can I ensure that across all tasks `taskA`, or all RMQ messages currently received, only one `ObjectB` with same `ItemId` can be processed at the time?**

***Example***:

`ObjectA (Id = 1, Items = {(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (1, "c")})`;

For given object, I must start parallel processing of Items `(1, "a")` and `(2, "b")` while `(1, "c")` should wait until Task that is processing `(1, "a")` has done processing because their `ItemId` is same.

Comment: Take those objects, add to additional list/collection objects with the same Id, and then process them one-by-one. So objects with different Ids will be in different collections, and be processed in parallel to each other; but objects with the same Id will be processed in the order.

Comment: Related: [Keyed Lock in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754211/keyed-lock-in-net) and [Asynchronous locking based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138179/asynchronous-locking-based-on-a-key)

Answer (score 0):

If you use containers you need to register as a Singleton.

In the example, a lock is created for each key, and the new task will not be started while the previous one is running

```
public sealed class DelayTaskProcessor
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _syncDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    private readonly object _sync = new object();

    public Task Create(Action action, string id)
    {
        return new Task(() =>
        {

            object currentSync = null;
            lock (_sync)
            {
                if (_syncDict.ContainsKey(id))
                {
                    currentSync = _syncDict[id];
                }
                else
                {
                    currentSync = new object();
                    _syncDict.Add(id, currentSync);
                }
            }

            lock (currentSync)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Start: {id}");
                action?.Invoke();

            }
        });
    }
}
        public sealed class ObjectA
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public List<ObjectB> Items { get; set; }
        }
        public sealed class ObjectB
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new DelayTaskProcessor();
        var objectA = new ObjectA
        {
            Id = 1, Items = new List<ObjectB>()
                {
                    new ObjectB {Id=1, Value="a"},
                    new ObjectB {Id=1, Value="a2"},
                    new ObjectB {Id=2, Value="b"},
                    new ObjectB {Id=3, Value="c"}
                }
            };
        var tasks = new List<Task>(objectA.Items.Count);
        foreach (var item in objectA.Items)
        {
            var task = p.Create(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Id},{item.Value}");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);

            }, $"b:{item.Id}");
            tasks.Add(task);
            task.Start();
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
        foreach (var t in tasks)
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                exceptions.Add(t.Exception);
                
            }
            using (t) { }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide me with example of creating task?

Comment: I added to answer

Comment: Since I am quite struggling with this, I have few more questions. If I have 5 tasks to execute inside foreach, do I need to make p.Create... 5 times. Also, how can I know when all tasks for current item are finished? Can I make something like list of tasks, and then just use Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks)?

Comment: I added task list to answer and wait

Answer (score 0):

I had to combine solution from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31194647/14281369) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34754890/14281369), and the code that works for me is:

```
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<object, RefCounted<SemaphoreSlim>> _lockDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, RefCounted<SemaphoreSlim>>();

    private sealed class RefCounted<T>
    {
        public RefCounted(T value)
        {
            RefCount = 1;
            Value = value;
        }

        public int RefCount { get; set; }
        public T Value { get; private set; }
    }

    public DelayTaskProcessor()
    {
        
    }

    public async Task<bool> ManageConcurrency(object taskId, Func<Task> task)
    {
        await GetOrCreate(taskId).WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            await task();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            RefCounted<SemaphoreSlim> item;
            lock (_lockDict)
            {
                item = _lockDict[taskId];
                --item.RefCount;
                if (item.RefCount == 0)
                    _lockDict.TryRemove(taskId, out var removed);
            }
            item.Value.Release();
        }
    }

    private SemaphoreSlim GetOrCreate(object key)
    {
        RefCounted<SemaphoreSlim> item;
        lock (_lockDict)
        {
            if (_lockDict.TryGetValue(key, out item))
            {
                ++item.RefCount;
            }
            else
            {
                item = new RefCounted<SemaphoreSlim>(new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));
                _lockDict[key] = item;
            }
        }
        return item.Value;
    }
}
```

Pleas, feel free to comment on this.