# Send parallel requests but only one per host with HttpClient and Polly to gracefully handle 429 responses

Tags: c#, .net-core, web-crawler, tpl-dataflow, polly

**Intro:**

I am building a single-node web crawler to simply validate URLs are `200 OK` in a .NET Core console application. I have a collection of URLs at different hosts to which I am sending requests with `HttpClient`. I am fairly new to using Polly and TPL Dataflow.

**Requirements:**

1. I want to support sending multiple HTTP requests in parallel with a
   configurable `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`.
2. I want to limit the number of parallel requests to any given host to 1 (or configurable). This is in order to gracefully handle per-host `429 TooManyRequests` responses with a Polly policy. Alternatively, I could maybe use a Circuit Breaker to cancel concurrent requests to the same host on receipt of one `429` response and then proceed one-at-a-time to that specific host?
3. I am perfectly fine with not using TPL Dataflow at all in favor of maybe using a Polly Bulkhead or some other mechanism for throttled parallel requests, but I am not sure what that configuration would look like in order to implement requirement #2.

**Current Implementation:**

My current implementation works, except that I often see that I'll have `x` parallel requests to the same host return `429` at about the same time... Then, they all pause for the retry policy... Then, they all slam the same host again at the same time often still receiving `429`s. Even if I distribute multiple instances of the same host evenly throughout the queue, my URL collection is overweighted with a few specific hosts that still start generating `429`s eventually.

After receiving a `429`, I think I only want to send one concurrent request to that host going forward to respect the remote host and pursue `200`s.

Validator Method:

```
public async Task<int> GetValidCount(IEnumerable<Uri> urls, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var validator = new TransformBlock<Uri, bool>(
        async u => (await _httpClient.GetAsync(u, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken)).IsSuccessStatusCode,
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = MaxDegreeOfParallelism}
    );
    foreach (var url in urls)
        await validator.SendAsync(url, cancellationToken);
    validator.Complete();
    var validUrlCount = 0;
    while (await validator.OutputAvailableAsync(cancellationToken))
    {
        if(await validator.ReceiveAsync(cancellationToken))
            validUrlCount++;
    }
    await validator.Completion;
    return validUrlCount;
}
```

The Polly policy applied to the HttpClient instance used in `GetValidCount()` above.

```
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> waitAndRetryTooManyRequests = Policy
    .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(3,
        (retryCount, response, context) =>
            response.Result?.Headers.RetryAfter.Delta ?? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(120),
        async (response, timespan, retryCount, context) =>
        {
            // log stuff
        });
```

**Question:**

How can I modify or replace this solution to add satisfaction of requirement #2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpClient TimeOut and Polly Bulkhead Policy problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68266935/httpclient-timeout-and-polly-bulkhead-policy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to introduce some sort of a flag `LimitedMode`  to detect that this particular client is entered in limited mode. Below I declare two policies - one simple retry policy just to catch TooManyRequests and set the flag. The second policy is a out-of-the-box `BulkHead` policy.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        /* other configuration */

        var registry = services.AddPolicyRegistry();

        var catchPolicy = Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r =>
            {
                LimitedMode = r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests;
                return false;
            })
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(1, i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)); 

        var bulkHead = Policy.BulkheadAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(1, 10, OnBulkheadRejectedAsync);

        registry.Add("catchPolicy", catchPolicy);
        registry.Add("bulkHead", bulkHead);

        services.AddHttpClient<CrapyWeatherApiClient>((client) =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("hosturl");
        }).AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry(PolicySelector);
    }
```

Then you may want to dynamically decide on which policy to apply using the `PolicySelector` mechanism: in case the limited mode is active - wrap bulk head policy with catch 429 policy. If the success status code received - switch back to regular mode without a bulkhead.

```
    private IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> PolicySelector(IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry<string> registry, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var catchPolicy = registry.Get<IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>>("catchPolicy");
        var bulkHead = registry.Get<IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>>("bulkHead");
        if (LimitedMode)
        {
            return catchPolicy.WrapAsync(bulkHead);
        }

        return catchPolicy;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that creates a [`TransformBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2) which prevents concurrent execution for messages with the same key. The key of each message is obtained by invoking the supplied `keySelector` function. Messages with the same key are processed sequentially to each other (not in parallel). The key is also passed as an argument to the `transform` function, because it can be useful in some cases.

```
public static TransformBlock<TInput, TOutput>
    CreateExclusivePerKeyTransformBlock<TInput, TKey, TOutput>(
    Func<TInput, TKey, Task<TOutput>> transform,
    ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions,
    Func<TInput, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null)
{
    if (transform == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transform));
    if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));
    if (dataflowBlockOptions == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataflowBlockOptions));
    keyComparer = keyComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;

    var internalCTS = CancellationTokenSource
        .CreateLinkedTokenSource(dataflowBlockOptions.CancellationToken);

    var maxDOP = dataflowBlockOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism;
    var taskScheduler = dataflowBlockOptions.TaskScheduler;

    var perKeySemaphores = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, SemaphoreSlim>(
        keyComparer);

    SemaphoreSlim maxDopSemaphore;
    if (maxDOP == DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded)
    {
        maxDopSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(Int32.MaxValue);
    }
    else
    {
        maxDopSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxDOP, maxDOP);

        // The degree of parallelism is controlled by the semaphore
        dataflowBlockOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded;

        // Use a limited-concurrency scheduler for preserving the processing order
        dataflowBlockOptions.TaskScheduler = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair(
            taskScheduler, maxDOP).ConcurrentScheduler;
    }

    var block = new TransformBlock<TInput, TOutput>(async item =>
    {
        var key = keySelector(item);
        var perKeySemaphore = perKeySemaphores
            .GetOrAdd(key, _ => new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));

        // Continue on captured context before invoking the transform
        await perKeySemaphore.WaitAsync(internalCTS.Token);
        try
        {
            await maxDopSemaphore.WaitAsync(internalCTS.Token);
            try
            {
                return await transform(item, key).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (!(ex is OperationCanceledException))
            {
                internalCTS.Cancel(); // The block has failed
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                maxDopSemaphore.Release();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            perKeySemaphore.Release();
        }
    }, dataflowBlockOptions);

    dataflowBlockOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDOP; // Restore initial value
    dataflowBlockOptions.TaskScheduler = taskScheduler; // Restore initial value
    return block;
}
```

Usage example:

```
var validator = CreateExclusivePerKeyTransformBlock<Uri, string, bool>(
    async (uri, host) =>
    {
        return (await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption
            .ResponseHeadersRead, token)).IsSuccessStatusCode;
    },
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 30,
        CancellationToken = token,
    },
    keySelector: uri => uri.Host,
    keyComparer: StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

All [execution options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions) are supported (`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, `BoundedCapacity`, `CancellationToken`, `EnsureOrdered` etc).

Below is an overload of the `CreateExclusivePerKeyTransformBlock` that accepts a synchronous delegate, and another method+overload that returns an [`ActionBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) instead of a `TransformBlock`, with the same behavior.

```
public static TransformBlock<TInput, TOutput>
    CreateExclusivePerKeyTransformBlock<TInput, TKey, TOutput>(
    Func<TInput, TKey, TOutput> transform,
    ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions,
    Func<TInput, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null)
{
    if (transform == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transform));
    return CreateExclusivePerKeyTransformBlock(
        (item, key) => Task.FromResult(transform(item, key)),
        dataflowBlockOptions, keySelector, keyComparer);
}

// An ITargetBlock is similar to an ActionBlock
public static ITargetBlock<TInput>
    CreateExclusivePerKeyActionBlock<TInput, TKey>(
    Func<TInput, TKey, Task> action,
    ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions,
    Func<TInput, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null)
{
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
    var block = CreateExclusivePerKeyTransformBlock(async (item, key) =>
        { await action(item, key).ConfigureAwait(false); return (object)null; },
        dataflowBlockOptions, keySelector, keyComparer);
    block.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<object>());
    return block;
}

public static ITargetBlock<TInput>
    CreateExclusivePerKeyActionBlock<TInput, TKey>(
    Action<TInput, TKey> action,
    ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions,
    Func<TInput, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null)
{
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
    return CreateExclusivePerKeyActionBlock(
        (item, key) => { action(item, key); return Task.CompletedTask; },
        dataflowBlockOptions, keySelector, keyComparer);
}
```

---

**Caution:** This class allocates one `SemaphoreSlim` per key, and keeps a reference to it until the class instance is finally garbage collected. This could be an issue in case the number of different keys is huge. There is an implementation of a less allocatey async lock [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138179/asynchronous-locking-based-on-a-key/65256155#65256155), that stores internally only the `SemaphoreSlim`s that are currently in use (plus a small pool of released `SemaphoreSlim`s that can be reused), which could replace the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, SemaphoreSlim>` used by this implementation.

Comment: **Caution:** The above implementation does not have an efficient input queue. If you feed this block with millions of items, the memory usage will explode.