# Exception in creating a file in multithreaded application - "File being used by another process"

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, concurrency, download

I am using the following code in C# Windows Service to create or overwrite an existing file.

```
function DonwnloadFile(string destinationfolder, string filename)
{
    using (var outputFileStream = System.IO.File.Create(
        destinationfolder + "\\" + filename, BUFFER_SIZE))
    {
        //Downloads a large file from cloud and writes it to the outputFileStream
        //...
        //...
    }
}
```

While the file (which is very large in size) is getting downloaded, another request to `DownloadFile` method is made since the source file got updated.
However, an exception is thrown:

> The process cannot access the file '[FileName with Path]' because it is being used by another process.

How do I implement a solution so that subsequent requests to overwrite the same file wait till the previous file write operation for the same file finishes.
Also, the solution should allow requests to a overwrite a different file should not wait as it won't throw any exception.

Can I use lock while ensuring lock only works based on the filename.
Or can someone please suggest a better solution for the problem.

Note: `DonwloadFile` method would be called by a different thread each time.

Comment: Yeah you're going to need a lock to do this, there is no built-in functionality in Windows to wait on file access. Maybe a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>`

Comment: Note that, while using a synchronization primitive is cleaner, you can just use the file itself for synchronization. Wrap the file access with a try/catch, and reimplement a retry logic after a few seconds when it fails

Comment: You might find this interesting: [Asynchronous locking based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138179/asynchronous-locking-based-on-a-key). Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022754/send-parallel-requests-but-only-one-per-host-with-httpclient-and-polly-to-gracef/ "Send parallel requests but only one per host with HttpClient and Polly to gracefully handle 429 responses") one, in case you are interested for a TPL Dataflow approach.

Comment: Do you download the file from the Internet or do you want to copy the file?

Comment: Can you not make the download cancel-able if the source file gets changed?  Also, you will need the lock AND a retry-with-wait mechanism, since the OS ultimately "owns" the file I/O.