# C# Polly combining http error handler, retry, bulkhead and timeout to be used inside HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic, policywrap

I am trying to make some HTTP calls and I want to have retry, timeout, and bulkhead for maximum concurrent connections. This is my attempt. I don't know if the order of the `WrapAsync` function calls is correct. More specifically,

- I may sometimes get 4xx or 5xx response from the server and I want Polly to handle those
- I don't want a `HttpClient` to make more than 3 concurrent HTTP calls and I set the queue size to "infinite"
- If the server did not respond in 20 seconds then timeout that attempt
- For retries use an exponential timeout policy by exponentially increasing the timeout

My question is does this code do what I think it will do?

```cs
var betterPolicy = HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError().OrTransientHttpStatusCode()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(5, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)))
    .WrapAsync(Policy.BulkheadAsync(3, int.MaxValue /* queue size */))
    .WrapAsync(Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)));

var httpClient = new HttpClient(new PolicyHttpMessageHandler(betterPolicy));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of Polly there are many ways to combine/chain policies. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73106630/13268855) I have demonstrated the most common ones. I would highly encourage you to use `Policy.WrapAsync` static method because:

- It is easier to interpret the [escalation chain](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/resilience.md#esc):

  - the leftmost parameter is the most outer policy
  - the rightmost parameter is the most inner policy
- It enforces compile-time policy compatibility checks

```
var resilienceStrategy = Policy.WrapAsync(sharedBulkhead, localRetry, localTimeout);
```

I've used the prefix `shared` in case of Bulkhead policy because it needs to be shared between `HttpClient` calls otherwise it is useless. In case of Polly most of the policies are stateless but there are a few [stateful](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Statefulness-of-policies) (like Circuit Breaker or Bulkhead).

I would also suggest to read [this other post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68350320/13268855) which details how to enforce throttling in case of `HttpClient`. Long story short: Bulkhead is mainly designed [for CPU based computations](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Bulkhead#premise-one-fault-shouldnt-bring-down-the-whole-ship), not for I/O bound operations. [RateLimit](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Rate-Limit) policy might be a better fit for this.