# Accessing ConcurrentDictionary element while running Task

Tags: c#, thread-safety, task, concurrentdictionary

The given code attempts to run a fire-and-forget `Task` while acquiring a lock to avoid race conditions on a cached element.
while debugging the whole application I noticed bizarre behavior - getting to the same break point with the same key. That said, I'm not sure if the assumption  that `ConcurrentDictionary` guarantees that only one writer will be applied to the element as well as locking inside the `Task.Run` block will assure me that this and only this Task will have access to the element itself.

```
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        lock (GetLockContext(key, region))
        {
            try
            {
                object newValue = cacheInterceptor.Intercept<T>(ctx);
                Put(refreshContext.Key, newValue, refreshContext.Region, refreshAction);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                refreshContext.UpdteRefreshNeeded(true);
                LogError("HANDLE_REFRESH", null, null, ex);
            }
        });
    }
```

```
        private object GetLockContext(string key, string region)
        {
            string ctx = key + region;
            object lckCtx = CTX_REPO.GetOrAdd(ctx, (dontcare) => new object());

            return lckCtx;
        }
```

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> CTX_REPO
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what's going wrong and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lock (GetLockContext(key, region))` should guarantee that only one thread in the current process will enter the critical region for the same key/region combination. The only problems that I can think of are:

1. The `key + region` generates the same combination for different key/region pairs. For example `"ab" + "c"` and `"a" + "bc"`.
2. Your application is hosted, and the host starts a new process before the currently running process has terminated.

As a side note instead of locking synchronously you could consider using an asynchronous locker like the [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) class, in order to avoid blocking `ThreadPool` threads. You could check out this question for ideas:
[Asynchronous locking based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138179/asynchronous-locking-based-on-a-key).