# .NET Concurrent Dictionary Exchange Value

Tags: c#, .net, collections, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

Is there a data structure similar to [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2) and [`Interlocked.Exchange<T>(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.exchange#system-threading-interlocked-exchange-1(-0@-0)) that would allow you atomically to set a new value and retrieve the old value assigned to an arbitrary key? Doesn't seem possible with any of the `AddOrUpdate(...)` overloads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality is not included out of the box. An [API proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/83270) for a `Transact` method exists in the GitHub dotnet/runtime repository, that would offer this functionality, but currently hasn't created much traction. You could implement it manually though, using the rudimentary `TryGetValue`, `TryAdd` and `TryUpdate` methods:

```
public static TValue AddOrUpdate<TKey, TValue>(
    this ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> source,
    TKey key,
    Func<TKey, TValue> addValueFactory,
    Func<TKey, TValue, TValue> updateValueFactory,
    out bool oldValueExists,
    out TValue oldValue) where TKey : notnull
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(addValueFactory);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(updateValueFactory);
    while (true)
    {
        if (source.TryGetValue(key, out oldValue))
        {
            TValue newValue = updateValueFactory(key, oldValue);
            if (source.TryUpdate(key, newValue, oldValue))
            {
                oldValueExists = true;
                return newValue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TValue newValue = addValueFactory(key);
            if (source.TryAdd(key, addValueFactory(key)))
            {
                oldValueExists = false;
                oldValue = default;
                return newValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above implementation is a modified version of the existing [`AddOrUpdate`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.0/src/libraries/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs#L1354) implementation.

Comment: What about `TValue oldValue = default; _ = dict.AddOrUpdate(key, newValue, (key, old) => { oldValue = old; return newValue; });`

Comment: @Charlieface yes, this should work too. Unless some other thread races to delete the same key, and the current thread ended up adding the key, instead of updating its value. In which case the `oldValue` might not be associated with the exact last operation performed on the dictionary.

Comment: In that case wouldn't the lambda be executed again (because the dictionary now needs an "add" rather than "update") and therefore the `oldValue` would be overwritten back to `default`?

Comment: @Charlieface yes, this should do the trick. I wasn't considering this possibility as adequate when I posted my answer.

Comment: "wouldn't the lambda be executed again" - not if the value was deleted. It would hit [this line](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/libraries/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs#L1456). To avoid looping, you'd need to specify an `addValueFactory` that sets the default as well.

Comment: Regardless, I think this answer will perform better since it avoids creating a delegate with variable capture on each invocation.

Comment: @KyleMcClellan it depends. My answer calculates the hashcode of the key at least two times, while the native `AddOrUpdate` calculates it only once. So for a `TKey` of type `string`, I expect my answer to be slower.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following extension functon

```c
public static TValue Exchange<TKey, TValue>(this ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> source, TKey key, TValue value)
    where TKey : notnull
{
    TValue oldValue = default;
    _ = dict.AddOrUpdate(key,
        key => { oldValue = default; return newValue; },
        (key, old) => { oldValue = old; return newValue; });
    return oldValue;
}
```

Comment: As discussed in Theodor's answer, I think you need `_ = dict.AddOrUpdate(key, key => { oldValue = default; return newValue; }, (key, old) => { oldValue = old; return newValue; });`

Comment: You're right, fixed. And yes probably less efficient, but simpler.