# Can two identical strings ever object compare to different instances?

Tags: .net, string, equality, string-interning

Section 7.10.7 of C# Programming Language (A. Hejlsberg, et. al, 2011 Fourth Edition, Annotated for 4.0 ) states that, " When two separate string instances contain the exact same sequences of characters, the values of the strings are equal, but the references are different."

Is this ever the run-time case?  Won't the .NET runtime and BCL ALWAYS intern two identical strings to the same reference box?

I understand the book is talking about a 'spec', but the next question - is there ANY known implementation of C# that behaves this way?

EDIT

OK what's really bothering me is this:

```
String FirstOne = "StatusOK"
String MiddleOne = "StatusOK"
String LastOne = "StatusOK"

Integer FindMeOne(object AnythingtoFind) { return MsgLst.IndexOf(AnythingToFind) }

List<String> MsgLst;
MsgLst.Add(FirstOne);
MsgLst.Add(MiddleOne);
Msglst.Add(LastOne);

Integer foo = FindMeOne( LastOne );
```

I don't expect foo to be 1!
I guess I'm just silly that way.

UPDATE
    All I have to do to get what I want is:

```
public class MyNiceStringsThatICanFind 
{ 
private String foobar;
}
```

But again this is not nice. If objects track themselves by HashCode, what is so stinking special about a string? Why doesn't the runtime look at your Objects and see, hey, maybe it is the exact same thing inside, let's make it the same reference.

Comment: I just built and ran this using VS 2013; Framework V4.5.2 and it returned 0 as expected and documented. Perhaps you have a typo somewhere. Likewise with Framework V4.5. This happens both with `static List<object> MsgLst;` and with `static List<string> MsgLst;`.

Comment: Are you expecting the run-time to keep track of all the strings in memory as it computes a new string to see if the new string should share a reference? This would be especially wasteful for a computation that generated a lot of temporary strings.

Comment: If I refer to a String as an Object, then I want that Object back. Period.  Interning causes a leak in that metaphor.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens ok, i'm just saying I don't want the first one, I want the last one. So that's 2 that I expect, not 0.

Comment: Documentation for `List<T>IndexOf(T)`: *Searches for the specified object and returns the zero-based index of the **first occurrence** within the entire List<T>.* Link:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeah, I got you man.

Answer (score 1):

This equality behaviour only applies to string literals (although see [`NoStringInterning`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilationrelaxations.aspx)). If you create equal strings at runtime they will not necessarily refer to the same instance:

```
var abc = "abc";
var ab = "ab";
var c = "c";

var abc2 = ab + c;
bool eq = Object.ReferenceEquals(abc, abc2);  //false

var interned = String.Intern(abc2);
bool ieq = Object.ReferenceEquals(interned, abc);  //true
```

Comment: And " (object)abc == (object)abc2 " will produce similar results?

Comment: @AndyzSmith - `==` for `object` tests reference equality, so yes.

Comment: Why am I seeing something like this "The common language runtime conserves string storage by maintaining a table, called the intern pool, that contains a single reference to each unique literal string declared or created programmatically in your program. Consequently, an instance of a literal string with a particular value only exists once in the system." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Created programmatically being the key phrase.

Comment: Mr. Skeet has something enlightening to add: "As others have explained, string interning occurs for all string literals, but not on "dynamically created" strings (e.g. those read from a database or file, or built using StringBuilder or String.Format.)"  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555871/c-strings-with-same-contents